# Regular Expressions \w character class and equals sign

Tags: java, regex, equals

I am creating a regular expression to match the string

> @servername:port:databasename

and through https://regex101.com/ I came up with

> \@(((\w+.*-*)+)?\w+)(:\d+)(:\w+)

which matches

e.g. @CORA-PC:1111:databasename or @111.111.1.111:111:databasename

However when I use this regular expression to pattern match in my java code the String @CORA-PC:1111:database=name is also matched.

Why is \w matching the = equals sign? I also tried [0-9a-zA-Z] but it also matched the = equals sign?

Can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks!

Comment: It is `.*` that can match the `=`. Try [`@(\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*)?(:\d+)(:\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/bA2mB4/1) (in Java, double the backslashes)

Comment: Do you need to match `@CORA-PC:1111:database` in `@CORA-PC:1111:database=name` or do you want to avoid matching the whole string altogether?

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply Wiktor - I want to match the whole string (it is to be used as a web form field validator) i.e. @CORA-PC:1111:databasename only. so if database=name is entered the validation should fail. This expression works perfectly in regex101 but fails in the java/javascript code.

Comment: It does not fail there if you write it correctly. Please share the code you have. I added code examples for Java and JS.

Comment: String jdbcUrl = "@CORA-PC:1111:databaseName=DB212";
   
boolean valid = false;
   
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(@(\\w+(?:[-.]\\w+)*)?(:\\d+)(:\\w+))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(jdbcUrl);
if (m.find()){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.*` is a greedy dot matching subpattern that matches the whole line and then backtracks to accommodate for the subsequent subpatterns. That is why the pattern can match a `=` symbol (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA2mB4/3) - Group 3 matches that part with `=`) .

Your pattern is rather fragile, as the first part contains nested quantifiers with optional subpatterns that slows down the regex execution and [causes other issues](https://regex101.com/r/zM2dJ1/1). You need to make it more linear.

```
@(\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*)?(:\d+)(:\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA2mB4/1)

The regex will match

- `@` - `@` symbol
- `(\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*)?` - an optional group matching

  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `(?:[-.]\w+)*` - 0+ sequences of a `-` or `.` (`[-.]`) followed with 1+ word chars
- `(:\d+)` - a `:` symbol followed with 1+ digits
- `(:\w+)` - a `:` symbol followed with 1+ word chars

If you need to avoid partial matching, use `String#matches()` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA2mB4/2)).

**NOTE**: In Java, backslashes must be doubled.

Code example ([Java](https://ideone.com/AeYc5T)):

```
String s = "@CORA-PC:1111:databasename";
String rx = "@(?:\\w+(?:[-.]\\w+)*)?:\\d+:\\w+";
System.out.println(s.matches(rx));
```

Code example (JS):

```js
var str = '@CORA-PC:1111:databasename';
alert(/^@(?:\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*)?:\d+:\w+$/.test(str));
```

Comment: Capture groups can be adjusted further, depending on what you need to obtain as the final result. For now, you can even use `@(?:\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*)?:\d+:\w+`.